# Getting an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module' error with Hangman Game code

Tags: javascript

I am learning web development and trying to use Vanilla JS to create a Hangman Game. The game runs as expected with a words array in the main.js file but when I import words from a different file, Browser shows the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module".

I fixed this by specifying type = "module" in the index.html file but now, I am getting reference error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hangman is not defined" (hangman is an instance of the Hangman object).

I tried adding a function and calling it using the load eventListener but the issue persisted.

I am primarily wondering about:

1. Is there another way to fix the syntax error about "import declerations".
2. Why am I getting the reference error even though I have set 'hangman' as a global variable in main.js?

P.S - I am not sure about how much info to add so here is the github link for [main.js](https://github.com/shamshadCodes/HangmanGame/blob/main/main.js) and [index.html](https://github.com/shamshadCodes/HangmanGame/blob/main/index.html). I will appreciate feedback on my question to make sure I ask questions more efficiently from the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Because you use javascript module syntax you have to declare `<script type='module'>` you can omit this syntax or use compiler (esbuild, webpack...) if you don't want to use `type='module'`
- You get `hangman is undefined` error because `hangman` is declared in `main.js` and `main.js` is imported as a `module` so it is local please include functions like `logAndCreateButton` in `main.js` or in `main.js` use `window.hangman = hangman` (not recommended) to solve the problem

Comment: the issue with doing `window.hangman = hangman` is that you're exposing the `hangman` instance to the user and he can it through the developer console.

Comment: @EkkoKo yes he has a code that uses `hangman` variable in html so we need to inject `hangman` from `main.js` into `window`

Comment: @EkkoKo I also said it's not recommended but he can do it if he wants

Comment: or just move that code into the `main.js` which I think is a better practice, that way you don't expose anything that you shouldn't to the user.

Comment: @EkkoKo That's right . but more solutions is more knowledge

Comment: I agree with you 100%! There is not doubt about it, just wanted to mention the consequences about doing it in that approach

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the code, I found the error is being caused beacuse of the defining order, inside `index.html` there is a `<script>` tag that you define your on load that on click calls `hangman.reset()` but `hangman` inside the scope of that script is not defined, by moving all of the content of the script tag into the `main.js` file now the `hangman` instance is in scope of the `logAndCreateButton` function and that should fix your issue.

TLDR: move the contents of the script that is inside `index.html` into `main.js`